# Xamarin iOs Build failed : Storyboards

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

It has been a month that I can't build my Xamarin iOs project. This seemed to have started after I updated to the new Xcode for the free provisioning. Since then, I tried finding a solution to this problem, but I haven't seem to find one.

When building the application, Xamarin Studio prompt me with an error that only indicates the name of my storyboard without any description. (The build action used for my storyboard is *InterfaceDefinition* which is the default one I guess)

[image]

Xamarin Studio also opens the Storyboard when the build failed.

I tried to open the storyboard in Xcode and everything went fine. So I really don't understand what is happening with my storyboards.

I even tried to open it with Visual Studio and the build failed but with no error.

Any help would be welcomed !
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: this is happening also in the beta version of Xamarin studio? (5.10)

Comment: Yes, I just tried doing it in the beta version but, still, it won't work.

Comment: After updating XCode did you open it and accepted the new license agreements ? If the license is not accepted Xamarin seems to throw random errors sometimes.

Comment: Yes I did when setting up for the free provisionning on my iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error.
I found the problem. In my storyboard, I added a tableview with static cell. => this caused the error. 
Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances
Just changed my tableview to dynamic Prototype and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cause can be using same storyboard identifier for two view controllers. I faced this error and was able to detect it by opening storyboard file in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same StoryBoard.Id property set on different UIViewControllers is another cause.